# Animating Button in Android

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

I am new to animations in android so please don't mark me negative. I am trying to animate positon of a button using translate animation.

**What I want to do:**

When user click the button, the button should first move towards extreme right of the display such that it is no longer visible. It should then come back to its original position from the left of the display.

[image: What I want]

**What actually is happening (Problem):**

When user clicks the button, the button first comes from the left of display and then accelerate towards the right of the display.

***animation.xml :***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:duration="200"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:startOffset="200"
        android:toXDelta="0%p" />

</set>
```

Comment: In first translate remove `p` in `android:fromXDelta="0%p"`, in second remove `p` in `android:toXDelta="0%p"`. `p` means calculate offset from parent position, without it it would calculate offset from this view position.

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude try this code it think it will fix your issue:

```
<translate
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="100%p" />
<translate

    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="1"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:startOffset="200"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p" />
<translate

    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:startOffset="210"
    android:toXDelta="0%p" />
```

Just remember the first translation will take your button to the right , so that mean the current button position is situated there (100%p) base on your animation set, so you need to find a way to set it quickly to the position you want it to start next, hence the translate i added in the middle.

Hope it will help

Comment: Thanks man, It worked. But I still don't get it. Why my code was not working? I thought the translate block will execute in sequence one after another. But actually it wasn't.

Comment: i think i explain myslef in my answer also %p you calculting the translate from the parent position. Have a look here for more explanation about animation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/package-summary.html and dont forget to select my answer if it was helpful to you

Comment: I know %p will calculate the offset from parents position. First translate block should set the button position to extreme right (100%p) and second translate block should immediately set its position to extreme left (-100%p) and then move it to right (0%p).

Comment: The why is not working since you know so well what you are doing?

Comment: Please don't mind I am just a beginner. Can you please explain what was I doing wrong why was the second translate block executing first, I don't even know if it was executing first, I am saying this because the button was first moving from left to original position instead of moving from original to extreme right.

Comment: Please correct me If I am wrong, first translate will move the button to 100%p. Now if we have to translate it from -100%p to 0%p, we have to first translate it from 100%p to -100%p. It can't just automatically jump directly from 100%p to -100%p. Right ?